# Get value of inside input tag when clicked outer div in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a program looping same `<div>` a number of times.

```
<div class="check"><input type="hidden" class="value" value="1" />Click 1</div>
<div class="check"><input type="hidden" class="value" value="2" />Click 2</div>
<div class="check"><input type="hidden" class="value" value="3" />Click 3</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In above HTML code every `<div>` and `<input>` tag has same class name, So How can I access input value for only clicked  class.

I am using following JQuery but getting only same values.

```
$('.check').click(function(){
var ans =    $('.value').val();
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hyvto0aa/

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = $('#result');

$('.check').on('click',function(){
    $(result).html($(this).find('.value').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type `$('.value')` you fetch all of `.value` items - and when you ask for `.val()` you fetch the value of the first one in the list.

Try this:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var ans = $(this).find('.value').val();
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```

`$(this)` is the element which was clicked,  and using `.find` will find the .value that happens to be in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a context:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var ans = $('.value', $(this)).val();
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add context and use the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) jQuery method:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var ans = $(this).find('.value').val();
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```

see **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyvto0aa/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var ans =    $('.value').val();
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```

you may use this:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var ans = $(this).children()[0].val(); // <-- This is the value for selected div
    $('#result').html(ans);
});
```